# How to overlay multiple images using scale2ref in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having more than 100 images and I want to overlay by using scale2ref in FFmpeg but I can only use scale2ref with 1 image and I don't know how to use it with more than 2 images. Currently, I am using this command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i gta5.mp4 -i 100%.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(300/300)*ih/4/sar:ih/4[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,2,4)\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

How to use more than 2 images in this?

Comment: `100%.png` is not a valid string for an image sequence.

Comment: See the [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for how to input a series of images.